# Efficiently compute many inner products in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, bsxfun

I am working on a project for which I need to compute a lot of inner products in high dimensions. I am aware that we should always try to vectorize operations in matlab, but I am not sure how to do this ...

Lets say we have two matrices, `A` and `B` of size `N x d` where `N` is the number of inner products to compute in `d` dimensions.

It is easy to implement using for-loops, but I suspect more efficient ways exist. A for-loop implementation might look like this:

```
innerprods=zeros(N,1);
for i=1:N
    innerprods(i)=A(i,:)*B(i,:)';
end
```

Does anyone have ideas how to vectorize this? I guess `bsxfun` should come into play at some point, but I cannot figure out how to use it for this ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicion regarding `bsxfun` is entirely justified! You can efficiently compute inner products using the following one-liner with `bsxfun` and the good old [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/colon.html):

```
innerprods=sum(reshape(bsxfun(@times,A(:),B(:)),N,d),2);
```

For a more detailed explanation of what's going on here:

```
    bsxfun(@times,A(:),B(:)) --> element-wise product, returns Nd x 1 vector
    reshape( ^^^ , N, d)      --> reshape into N x d matrix
    sum( ^^^ , 2)             --> sum over columns to get N x 1 vector
```

**EDIT**: I did some timings to give some idea as to the performance difference. I used [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) R2010b (don't ask ...). The figure shows some empirical results using the loop in your question and the one-liner I suggest for `N=500` and varying number of dimensions. Using loops is 2 to 8 times slower than the approach using `bsxfun`. The speed difference may be larger for newer versions of [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) due to better parallellization.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

What about the simple:

```
sum(A.*B,2)
```

A simple test (R2013a WinVista 32bit Core duo):

```
N = 8e3;
A = rand(N);
B = rand(N);

tic
out = zeros(N,1);
for ii = 1:N
    out(ii) = A(ii,:)*B(ii,:)';
end
toc

tic
out2 = sum(A.*B,2);
toc

all(out-out2 < 1e5*eps) % note difference in precision
```

Times

```
loop     5.6 sec
multsum  0.8 sec
```

### Additional tests on R2013a Win7 64 Xeon E5

```
Avg time loop:           2.00906 seconds
Avg time multSum:        0.18114 seconds
Avg time bsxfun:         0.18203 seconds
Avg time reshapeMultSum: 0.18088 seconds
```

The main take-away points:

- looping in this case is vastlly **inefficient** (expected);
- `bsxfun()` is totally **redundant**, although the overhead is not substantial (expected);
- Reshaping into a column and then back to a matrix is also expected to provide benefits due to the internal 'preference' of the MATLAB engine for **columnwise** operations (i.e. along rows first);
- for syntax **clarity** I still recommend multSum: `sum(A.*B,2)`.

The testing suite (avg times on 100 trials, fixed matrix size 8e3, equality of results to 1e5*eps):

```
N = 8e3;
A = rand(N);
B = rand(N);

tic
for r = 1:100
    out = zeros(N,1);
    for ii = 1:N
        out(ii) = A(ii,:)*B(ii,:)';
    end
end
sprintf('Avg time loop: %.5f seconds', toc/100)

tic
for r = 1:100; out2 = sum(A.*B,2);                                  end
sprintf('Avg time multSum: %.5f seconds', toc/100)

tic
for r = 1:100; out3 = sum(reshape(bsxfun(@times,A(:),B(:)),N,N),2); end
sprintf('Avg time bsxfun: %.5f seconds', toc/100)

tic
for r = 1:100; out4 = sum(reshape(A(:).*B(:),N,N),2);               end
sprintf('Avg time reshapeMultSum: %.5f seconds', toc/100)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have marked the answer of Marc since it seems to perform better for large values of N and d.

Comment: @JeffDun I am a bit puzzled because bsxfun is completely redundant. I will try to do more tests and see if something interesting unveils.

Comment: Hi @OlegKomarov, nice to see you are doing additional tests. I agree that your approach seems equivalent to mine. In fact, I liked your code more than mine when I saw it. For some reason my timings disagree, though. For large matrices, the bsxfun approach appears to be up to 40% faster. I have no idea why, though.

Comment: Can you post your achitecture, matlab version and timings for the above test for comparison? Also, what do you mena by big matrices? (Note that 8e3 by 8e3 has 64 mil elements and is ~488 MB of RAM)